# problem with amd gpu on ubuntu 16 .04

Tags: drivers, graphics, fglrx

I've just updated my ubuntu 15.10 to ubuntu 16.04 lts. I've got some problem with my decicated amd gpu(amd radeon r5 m335). I known that ubuntu 16 doesn't support amd proprietary drivers, but there are open-source alternatives that should work. I don't need graphical performance, i've got also an intel hd 530(and i was used to switch the amd gpu off and use only intel hd for a better battery life).
 I decided to do the upgrade  ubuntu  16, but it does not recognize the amd card! i was used to receive this boot message: radeon init error(-22). Since some days i don't the receive any message simply the system doen't see the amd card.
In ubuntu 15 i also received the radeon init message but it works! after some time i installed the proprietary driver(fglrx) and it works well.
In ubuntu 16 there's no way do see the amd card.

[this is the output of "additional drivers"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFkVV.png)
and
[this is the screenshoot of lspci](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB5ut.png)

I don't known the solution! but i think that i could do two things:
1)install thye fglrx propetary driver
2)manually configure the amdgpu driver

thanks for the advices and sorry for my english

Comment: Same thing here. I don't know how to switch between the graphics power-saving and discreet/dedicated. My lspci is the same, with added Display controller: Ati Radeon. Do you have the same?

Answer (score 4):

You can use AMDGPU-Pro  Driver "Beta" for Ubuntu 16.04.
From [this link](http://goo.gl/n2WveO):

> ### ​Installing the AMD GPU-PRO Driver
>
> There are four simple steps involved in the installation of the AMD
>   GPU-Pro Driver: Download, Extract, Install and Configure.  The
>   instructions to perform the installation have been simplified and
>   should take less than 10 minutes to complete.  Before installing the
>   driver, a quick note on how to check if your system already has AMD
>   GPU-PRO installed.
>
> #### System Check
>
> The easiest way to find out if you have AMD GPU-Pro already installed
>   on your Ubuntu System is to query the Debian package manager.
>
> Using the following command at a terminal will provide you with the
>   version of the AMD GPU-Pro stack on your system, or inform you that
>   there are no packages found:
>
> ```
> dpkg -l amdgpu-pro
> ```
>
> #### Download
>
> A direct link to download the Linux AMDGPU-PRO driver is given below
>   and it is also available on the [Driver Download Page](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download). This file
>   has a `tar.xz` extension which reflects a more-effective c​ompression
>   algorithm that (in most cases) creates a smaller archive than the more
>   common gzip format.
>
> [AMD Radeon™ Software AMD GPU-PRO Beta Driver – Linux® for Vulkan™
>   Version 16.15.1013 for Ubuntu 1​4.04.4​](https://www2.ati.com/drivers/beta/amdgpu-pro_16.15.2-277429.tar.xz)
>
> NOTE: This file can also be located via the [Driver Download Page](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download)
>   by locating your card and selecting the Linux Driver link.
>
> #### Extract
>
> After the archive is downloaded, extract the contents to a temporary
>   location from which you can install it. The example below assumes you
>   have downloaded the archive to `/tmp` and will extract to the same
>   location. If your file was downloaded into the `~/Downloads/` folder
>   by default, you can also extract and install from there, and
>   afterwards you can remove the install files.​
>
> ```
> cd /tmp
> ​tar -Jxvf amdgpu-pro_16.15.2-277429​.tar.xz
> ```
>
> #### Install
>
> Once the archive is expanded on the local machine, run the included
>   script (`amdgpu-pro-install`) to install the graphics stack.  During
>   the installation you will be required to provide sudo access, and also
>   to provide two confirmations to:​
>
> 1. Install the packages, and
> 2. Allow installation of "unverified" packages from the AMDGPU-PRO archive.   The script will use the package manager to install the
>      components of the graphics stack, with a short delay during the DKMS
>      (Dynamic Kernel Module Support) installation. From the directory where
>      you extracted the archive, issue the following command:
>
>    amdgpu-pro-driver/amdgpu-pro-install
>
> After this you can restart your machine to launch using the new
>   graphics stack.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. I did it for you this time, but next time, please don't post a link as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your post, the answer is obvious.  NO, the fglrx driver will not work with Ubuntu 16.04.it was deprecated for a reason in favor of the forthcoming AMDGPU drivers (closed source) from AMD. Sadly AMD is not supporting the R7 ot R5 with this new driver software. You are going to have to back pedal to 15.10 to get the graphics you wanted befoe updating. Those AMDGPU drivers ar e meant for the newerR9 series cards that can also handle Vulkan. (Sadly ours can not...)

I made the same mistake myself and updated to 16.04 only to find my card deprecated by the installer also. 
(R7 260x). Until the community writes a mew set of compatible drivers for your GPU, stick with fglrx for now. There was an article over on Phoronix that showed experimental use of AMDGPU on the R7 260X a while back, but the performance is just about the same as it was using Catalyst, not much of a performance boost. Save yourself a headache.